# Match slot to multiple values

Tags: action, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, speaker, google-assistant

In my skill I'm using a Custom Slot for a list of Programs. These programs have a list of synonyms/alias that resolve to the Program title if matched. Sometimes it's possible that multiple programs have a common synonym, in that case I would need to return to the webhook the list of the Programs instead of only one of the Programs with that Synonym.

In the following example, the two Programs have a common synonym "rubrica".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58ERo.png)

In my Intent I used the custom Slot type "programs" and flagged the "List" option
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9irk.png)

With the following utterance:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5uHL.png)

But if I try to say "mettere rubrica" the slot is filled with only one of the two options. Instead, I'd like the slot to be filled with a list of all programs that have that Synonym, how can I achieve this?Thanks in advance